# PHP:No such file or directory

Tags: php, api, bing

```
$response = file_get_contents($requestUri,0, $context);
```

gives the following errors

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you      forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\wamp\www\bing_basic.php on line 58

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&amp;Query=%27dfg%27): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\bing_basic.php on line 58
```

Any advice on how to go about removing them?? I am using a Bing API key to get results on a  HTML page using WAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `extension=php_openssl.dll` within your php.ini file, then restart your server.